# Porting Unix Sockets to Windows

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, unix, tcp

I have a simple C++ library that implements unix sockets and it works perfectly fine on Linux systems, however I'm facing the problem of porting part of my code to a Windows platform, which obviously does not support unix sockets. The alternative, as far as I understand, would be to implement TCP sockets, whoose principle is fairly similar (writing/reading from a TCP port instead of a specific file).

Contextually and logistically, would the conversion of the code be simple enough to implement on top of the existing code or I should rewrite the code from scratch?

Comment: You don't have to read/write to a TCP port. You will be reading/writing to a windows socket which may be TCP or UDP (at least those are the 2 I know of). You probably got down-voted because your question is too vague to answer specifically and depends upon how you've written your original implementation and what your objectives are.

Answer (score 1):

The **Berkeley API** does exist on Windows and is largely compatible with any other Berkeley Sockets implementation.

See the MSDN article "**Porting Socket Applications to Winsock**" for information about porting sockets code to Windows.

Comment: and what about boost::asio? would it coupare performance-wise?

Comment: I would use boost::asio if you are developing cross platform app or if you already using boost stuff.

Answer (score 1):

One common reason why sockets won't work on Windows is that you need to run [WSAStartup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to initiate the Winsock DLL. Like this:

```
WORD wVersionRequested;
WSADATA wsaData;
int err;

/* Use the MAKEWORD(lowbyte, highbyte) macro declared in Windef.h */
wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
if (err != 0) {
    /* Tell the user that we could not find a usable */
    /* Winsock DLL.                                  */
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", err);
    return 1;
}
```

Besides that, the Windows Sockets API (WSA) is pretty much as Berkeley sockets.